# What is the fastest way to write a matrix to a text file in Octave?

Tags: file, matlab, matrix, octave

I have a large matrix (2e6 x 3) which I have to write to a text file.

dlmwrite takes about 230s to achieve this task.

From your experience what is the fastest way to write a large matrix to a text file?

Comment: Did you try the `-ascii` option of `save`. That is, `save -ascii output.txt variableName`

Comment: Do you need to just save the data or does it need to be formatted in a text file? @petrichor's idea should work fine.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The following applies to MATLAB, but I suggest you try it in Octave. First of all, if you can - transpose the matrix. Here are examples using `fprintf` and `csvwrite` (essentially `dlmwrite`)

```
A = rand(3, 1e6);
tic;
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'w+');
for i=1:size(A, 1)
    fprintf(fid, '%f ', A(i,:));
    fprintf(fid, '\n');
end
fclose(fid);
toc

tic;
csvwrite('data.txt', A);
toc;

Elapsed time is 1.311512 seconds.
Elapsed time is 2.487737 seconds.
```

If not transposed, it will take ages indeed. [By default, `fprintf` flushes the buffer after every call](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/04/19/high-performance-file-io/). You can try to use `W` instead of `w` to open the file, but it does not improve the situation here too much.

Comment: You can avoid the explicit loop and use an `fprintf(fid,'%f %f %f\n',A)` Also, fprintf will recycle the format applied to the variables column-wise.  E.g: `tic;fid = fopen('data.txt', 'w+'); fprintf(fid, 'a=%f b=%f c=%f\n', A); fclose(fid);toc`
Elapsed time is 2.019833 seconds. and gives three numbers and a newline on each of the 1e6 lines.

Answer (score 7):

Did you try this? I'm not sure about it's speed as compared to dlmwrite.

```
a = [1 2;3 4];
save temp.txt a;
```

Comment: perhaps it should be used in this way: tic; save temp.txt A -ASCII; toc;

Answer (score 2):

Having a variable `data` you can save it in a `text` format with space separated values (including a header):

```
save out.txt data
```

The header can be simply removed using basic Unix command [`tail`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/tail.1.html) e.g. (on any Linux/Mac OS):

```
tail -n +6 out.txt > file.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, according to what @angainor says, one can even improve performance 
wrapping somehow

```
for i=1:size(A, 1)
   fprintf(fid, '%f ', A(i,:));
   fprintf(fid, '\n');
end
```

in chunks to avoid useless buffer flushing, i.e.doing

```
1. coverting (in memory) numbers->string + introduction of termination characters '\n' 
   (for say K matrix rows)
2. writing of the obtained string to file through fscanf.
```

Ought to try..

Answer (score 0):

Use this in Matlab:

```
 save -ascii output.txt variableName
```

Use this in Octave:

```
 save hello1.m variableName -ascii
```

Answer (score 0):

In my system

```
A = rand(3, 1e6);

# Method with fprintf
tic;
fid = fopen('data1.txt', 'w+');
for i=1:size(A, 1)
    fprintf(fid, '%f ', A(i,:));
    fprintf(fid, '\n');
end
fclose(fid);
toc

# Method with sprintf
tic;
s = "";
for i=1:size(A, 1)
    s = strcat( s, sprintf('%f ', A(i,:)) );
    s = strcat( s, sprintf('\n') );
end
fid = fopen('data2.txt', 'w+');
    fprintf(fid, '%s\n', s);
fclose(fid);
toc

# Method with save
tic;
save 'data3.txt' A;
toc;

return;  # Commented when the size is <= 1e5

# Method with csvwrite
tic;
csvwrite('data4.txt', A);
toc;
```

gives

```
>> Elapsed time is 5.36293 seconds.
Elapsed time is 6.43252 seconds.
Elapsed time is 6.09889 seconds.
```

Since `csvwrite` is about 10 times slower than the others, I only tried it with a size = 10^-5. In that case,

```
>> Elapsed time is 0.541885 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.657595 seconds.
Elapsed time is 0.576796 seconds.
Elapsed time is 4.24433 seconds.
```

My conclusions are:

1. The comparison in speed among the various methods is strongly dependent on the system. Then, you will have to try yourself.
2. The [proposal by Acorbe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12936330/2707864) does not meet his expectations.

Comment: You do realize that you have your dimensions transposed compared to the questions dimensions (3x1e6) vs (2e6x3)? If you use dimensions from the question, the speed results in octave change significantly. Especially for your second sprintf which becomes much slower in octave due to the loop, str concat and missing jit compiler.