# Write a text file in octave without header

Tags: matlab, file, octave

When I try to write a variable to text file in octave, by using this command `save -text hey.txt X`, the file get saved properly BUT with a header which I do not want.

File `hey.txt`

```
# Created by Octave 3.8.1, Wed Jun 08 10:03:36 2016 IST <kenden@kenden-Lenovo-G500>
# name: X
# type: matrix
# rows: 1686
# columns: 1
 767
 865
 860
 855... and so on.
```

How can I save a file without the header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use 'save -ascii', from the manual:

```
-ascii
Save a single matrix in a text file without header or any other information.
```

Comment: Then how would I retrieve it in a variable X?

Comment: X = load ( filenname );

Comment: Btw, why don't you want the header if you want to load it back in Octave? I thought the reason why you dont want the header is because you want to process the saved file in another Software.

Comment: Yes, I am processing it in python too for some other purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use

```
csvwrite('hey.txt', X)
```

instead :-)

In case you want the header simply removed, someone at [What is the fastest way to write a matrix to a text file in Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12932052/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-write-a-matrix-to-a-text-file-in-octave) noted to use something like this (adapted to your case):

```
save -text hey.txt X
```

and then in bash et al.:

```
$> tail -n +6 hey.txt > headless_hey.txt
```

Which works nicely, as long as Octave uses 6 lines for the header.
Based on the observation, that comments start the line with a `#` one might eventually use other tools filtering based on that fact (not a fixed set of lines) like so:

```
$> sed /^#.*$/d hey.txt > commentless_hey.txt
```

or solutions based on `grep -v ...`, ... .